# I CANT END MY WHILE LOOP IN FUNTIONS USING PYTHON3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Calculator:

    def get_input(self, get = input("Expression here press q to exit: ")):     
            pass
             
    def compute(self, res):
            pass
    def display(self):
          pass
calc = Calculator()   

while calc.get_input() != "q": 
    calc.get_input()
    calc.display()
    exit()
```

This is calculator like i just remove its data because of review issues here *so much code*
but the input must be example: 435+422
you must include the operation in input like that, this is done so my problem now is
i dont know how to loop it.
the out put must be

### -enter expression or "q" to exit : 2+2

### -enter expression or "q" to exit : 1+2

-enter expression or "q" to exit : q
-bye exit

i dont knooow

Comment: Don't make a function call in the argument of `get_input`

Comment: In your own words, what is the logic that would cause `calc.get_input()` to be equal to `"q"` when you type that input? What is your understanding of how function calls work? Are you familiar with the `return` keyword? What source are you using to learn Python?

Comment: Your function doesn't `return` anything so it implicitly returns `None`

Comment: In your own words, what is the purpose of classes in Python? What problem do you hope to solve by using the `class Calculator`, instead of just writing ordinary functions?

Comment: sorry, i am not familiar any of that because im just new in python i just started last month. I dont have any choice but to use class because that is the instruction of my prof. those fucntions names are given and we just have to complete and make an attributes. but ill search about that thankyouu so much !

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
class Calculator:
    def get_input(self):     
        user_input = input("Expression here press q to exit: ")
        return user_input
```

Instead of invoking input in arguments

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `get_input` doesn't return anything. So `calc.get_input()` allways evaluates to `None`
Try:

```
    class Calculator:

    def get_input(self):
        return input("Expression here press q to exit: ")
             
    def compute(self, res):
        pass
    def display(self):
        pass

calc = Calculator()   
while calc.get_input() != "q": 
    calc.get_input()
    calc.display()
    exit()
```